# How to get the maximum value of an element using cts:values in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to get the Maximum value of `<ID>` from all the documents present inside the database.

Sample Document-

```
<root xmlns="http://marklogic.com/sample">
 <node>
  <ID>3253523</ID>
  <value1>.....</value1>
  <value2>.....</value2>
  <value3>.....</value3>
  <value4>.....</value4>
   .....................
 </node>
</root>
```

The approach which i tried is as below-

1. I created a path namespace with prefix sa with uri `http://marklogic.com/sample`.
2. Created a path range index of type int with path as `/sa:root/sa:node/sa:ID`

3.Trying to fetch the maximum value from the database by using the below code-

`declare namespace sa = "http://marklogic.com/sample";
(cts:values(cts:path-reference('/sa:root/sa:node/sa:ID'), (), "descending"))[1]`

But this is giving me an empty sequence. Not sure what i am missing here.

Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Are you sure the node has the namespace `http://marklogic.com/sample`? I would expect the root element to look like `<root xmlns="http://marklogic.com/sample">`. The rest of your steps look like they would work.

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to add that in my sample document. But it looks like same whatever you mentioned.

Comment: Is it because of the int value is too long `3253523`.??

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a map with the namespace bindings as the third argument to [`cts:path-reference()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-reference).  See: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:path-reference

By the way, [`cts:max()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:max) will probably be the most efficient way to get the maximum value from a range index. See: http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:max

The approach would resemble the following fragment:

```
cts:max(
    cts:path-reference('/sa:root/sa:node/sa:ID', (),
        map:entry("sa", "http://marklogic.com/sample")
    ))
```

Hoping that helps,

Comment: @ehennum-- Can you please give me an example on how should i use `cts:max()` for this case.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by `Elijah Bernstein-Cooper` 
I just added the `xmlns="http://marklogic.com/sample"` namespace in the xml shared by you and inserted few xml files in the db.

Created the path namespace, path range index and ran the shared cts query and it worked perfectly so `Elijah` is correct you just need to specify the namespace in the xml.

Small change in your query is in `declare namespace` statement, prefix will be `sa` not `es`.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i modified the namespace. But somehow i am missing something and it is giving me an empty sequence.

Comment: Could you please provide the `cts:query`, `screenshot of xml saved in the DB from qconsole` and `screenshot of the path-namespace and path-range-index` from 8001 port. this will help me in helping you in less time.